# problem with gravity and sliding of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Well I have a problem, when I press a letter the player must climb or descend (depend of input player on y) and if I keep the letter pressed it should stay still on the wall without move, here is the problem with mo gravity and when I press the key the player don't stay on the wall, tha player continues sliding slow this is for the gravity on the game, I can't desability the gravity because I make special jumps of the wall. so my `velocity.y = 0` don't work. How can create a solution for this.

```
        wallDirX = GetDirectionWallPlayer();
        if (controller.collisions.left || controller.collisions.right)
        {
            stateWallPlayer.WallClimbing = true;
            if (directionalInput.y > 0)
            {
                if (velocity.y < wallClimbUpSpeedMax)
                {
                    velocity.y = wallClimbUpSpeedMax;
                }
            }
            else if (directionalInput.y < 0)
            {
                if (velocity.y < -wallClimbDownSpeedMax)
                {
                    velocity.y = -wallClimbDownSpeedMax;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't disable the gravity. You can enable it once again when you jump if you need it, and manupulate when its enabled for each case. Another solution i can suggest is to have it permantly disabled, and describe with code the logic of how the entity moves with gravity when it jumps, coding the parabolic movement physics yourself

Comment: @RustyBucketBay  because I have special jump with the wall and without gravity this jump go so high

Comment: activate the gravity back just before applying the jump force, or moving the player